# Incorrect display of multiple jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tabs

I came across a problem that I dont know how to solve or what is causing it.

Basically I have a page with jquery tabs. The tabs are loaded via ajax, just like in the example on the official jquery page. 
On the loaded pages however, I have further tabs. In other words you open the first page, that has tabs and one of the pages that opens within that tab has another list of tabs.

I made sure all the IDs are unique. However, what happens is that the page loads ok, no errors, everything working. I switch to the next tab, again, no problems, everything working and the new page loads with another list of tabs in it. And even those tabs work again. But then, when I swith back to the first original tab, it throws me a javascript error that tabs() is not a function and the whole structure of the page messes up.

Here is the first page I want to load:
http://meteopage.com/subdom/downloads/template/pages/station/report_annual.php?y=2012

The "Extremes" tab should then load this page:
http://meteopage.com/subdom/downloads/template/pages/station/report_annual1.php?y=2012

Separately they work fine, but if you try clicking the Extremes tab on the first page, it loads the second fine, but then when you switch back to the original Summary tab and again to the Extremes tab it is all messed up. In other words, if you keep on switching between the tabs, it only works ok the first time the page loads, but after switching there and back it throws me that error.

Thanks for any tips in advance

The code would basically be like this:

The first main page:

```
<div id="tabs" class="centered">
    <ul style="align:center">
            <li>
                <a href="#tabs-1"><?php echo lang("Summary")?></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="report_annual1.php?y=2012?></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1"></div>
 </div>
    <script>
    $(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    })
    </script>
```

Then the second page, which is loaded in the second tab has the exact same code, excelt the #tabs is called #tabs2 and the divs tabs-21, tabs22 etc.

Comment: show your code or add JSfiddle.....

Comment: Please add your code as @Pratik said as it's not helpful to people, how anyone  can answer.

Comment: triger the tabs for #tabs2 from the main page not from the ajax page

Comment: I tried that, that doesnt work at all, the tabs on the ajax page are then not generated and show as normal ul list